# How to load image from memory in SFML?

Tags: c++, memory, base64, png, sfml

I am currently trying to encode some png files in base64, and when the SFML app starts the files are decoded, loaded into memory and passed to the function that loads a texture from memory, however if I do this, I get an error which says that the file is unsupported or corrupted. If I save the file from memory and open it in a image viewer it is displayed without any errors.
Here is how I did everything, am I doing something wrong?:

**B64.cpp**

```
std::string StringFromFile(std::string file)
{
    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open(file, std::ios::binary);
    std::ostringstream out;
    out << fin.rdbuf();
    fin.close();
    std::string data(out.str());
    return data;
}

void Encode(std::string in, std::string out)
{
    std::ifstream ins;
    ins.open(in);
    base64::encoder enc(GetFileSize(in));
    std::ofstream outs;
    outs.open(out);
    enc.encode(ins, outs);
    ins.close();
    outs.close();
}

void* Decode(std::string in)
{
    std::ifstream ins;
    ins.open(in);
    base64::decoder dec(GetFileSize(in));
    std::ofstream outs;
    outs.open("/tmp.b64");
    dec.decode(ins, outs);
    std::string *file = new std::string(StringFromFile("/tmp.b64"));
    void* data;
    data = file;
    //std::remove("tmp.b64");
    ins.close();
    outs.close();
    return data;
}

size_t GetDataSize(std::string file)
{
    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open(file);
    std::ostringstream out;
    out << fin.rdbuf();
    fin.close();
    std::string data(out.str());
    return data.size();
}

size_t GetFileSize(std::string file)
{
    std::ifstream ins;
    ins.open(file, std::ios::ate | std::ios::binary);
    return ins.tellg();
}
```

**Game.cpp**

```
void Load()
{
    ...
    Encode("Textures/player.png", "Textures/player.b64");
    sf::Texture tstx;
    tstx.loadFromMemory(Decode("Textures/player.b64"), 1422);
    ...
}
```

Comment: If SFML reports "the file is unsupported or corrupted", then the file is probably corrupted. Have you tried saving the decoded data back to the disk and checked that the encoding/decoding actually worked?

Comment: @Lukas, I tried writing the data of the void pointer to a file by casting it to a string pointer, and the image loads without any problems in a image viewer or by the "LoadFromFile" function, however if I pass the void pointer itself to SFML, then I get the error.

Comment: How do you know it's 1422 bytes actually? Why don't you try `sizeof` the texture after the decoding?

Comment: Actually you should instead try: `data = file->c_str();` as the conversion from string is not the same as conversion from `char*`

Comment: @Nadarian, Yes It works if I use c_str()! Thank you! And I was choosing the wrong file size for the b64 decoder.